# Excel number format - Scaleable space instead of comma

Tags: excel, number-formatting

I want to format some financial data using spaces instead of commas to separate '000's.  I am struggling to get the format to scale to larger numbers

Excel scales the format perfectly with commas, using something like #,##0;(#,##0) expanding to add commas every 3 numbers.  e.g. 1234567890 converts to 1,234,567,890

However, I want to show this number as 1 234 567 890.

I can force a space into the format, using something like # ##0 which works for up to 6 digits but not more. I could use # ### ##0, but ideally want a scalable solution that can handle any number in the same way regardless of digits.

The above also runs into problems with negatives, as I end up with a space between the brackets on every variation other than the format I use.  I can fix -1234567 to (1 234 567) using (# ### ##0) but this becomes ( 123 456) for 6 digits rather than (123 456).

Is there a character code or something else to force a space and make it behave the same way as a comma in the number formatting code.

Comment: Have a look here for one option: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3f7f8cbf-1967-44b5-8bb9-2a2f8c6f109d/thousands-separator-in-excel-i-want-space-not-comma?forum=excel

Comment: If it is just for your workbook, go to `Tools-Options-Advanced-Editing` and specify the separators you want.  If it is for distributed workbooks, you'll likely need a VBA solution fired off a worksheet change macro.

Comment: Both comments above influence the settings of either your system or Excel. I think your solution should be vailable, but unfortunatily it doesn't work. It should be possible with customising number formats, but I think you discovered a bug in Excel. I tried `#" "##0`, `#_A##0` and `#\ ##0`  in Office 2010, but they all fail. Maybe it is solved in a new version?

Comment: Thanks.  As you all point out, the solutions work on my system, but aren't distributable.  I can't revert to VBA either unfortunately.  I've tried all the variation formats listed above, but as in 2010, they all fail in 2016 as well.  I'll work about using most likely mask for now, and will update if I come across away to do it.